# Как можно кликнуть на input[type='file']?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на мою кнопку, был клик на `input[type='file']`, чтобы вызвалось окно выбора файла.

Пробовал `.trigger('click')`, `.click()`.

Это работает при вводе из консоли браузера, в самом же коде - это не работает, нету никаких ошибок, просто нету клика.

Метод вызывается из объекта.

UPD: Не работает только в Chromium, в Firefox все отлично

Comment: если работает в кансоли и не работает в коде => проблема в коде..))

Comment: Но, та часть кода выполняется

Comment: код в студию...

Comment: Инпут скрытый небось?

Comment: @andreymal, нет, но он находится за рамками окна браузера.

Comment: @C.Raf.T, $('#input').click();

Comment: Важно, чтобы это было не просто в коде, а в коде, инициированном действием пользователя... Политика безопасности..

Comment: [ask] и/или [mcve]

Comment: @vp_arth, опубликуйте свой комментарий ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Arhad, опубликовал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такова **политика безопасности**

Важно, чтобы это было не просто в коде, а в коде, инициированном действием пользователя...

Т.е. в обработчике события пользовательского ввода, например, `click` - всё работает:

```js
document.getElementById('y')
  .addEventListener('click', () => 
    document.getElementById('x').click())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="x">
<br><br>
<button id="y">Click me</button>
```

А в коде, не инициированном пользователем, нет:

```js
setTimeout(() =>
  document.getElementById('x').click(), 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="x">
```

Answer (score 3):

да вродe работает... chrome Version 62.0.3202.75

```js
$("#y").click(()=>{$("#x").trigger("click")})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="x">
<br><br>
<button id="y">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Это работает потому что `y.onclick`. Замените на setTimeout - не будет работать.

Comment: Решено, спасибо